# Reload table in express without ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, pug

I need to be able to reload the tables without refreshing the whole page or if possible use use ajax to create an uncertain number of tables.Currently I pass an Json object to my uplink view and loop through it to create tables.

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');
var jsonfile;
var coordinator = './coordinator.json';
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    fs.accessSync(coordinator, fs.F_OK);
    jsonfile = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(coordinator, 'utf8'));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
  var json = req.uplinkjson;
  res.render('uplink', {
    'title': 'Coordinator  Report',
    'uplinkjson': jsonfile
  });
});

router.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: "Data hasn't been collected from the uplink",
    error: {}
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

```html
 
extends layout

block extra_js
 script.
  $(document).ready(function() {
   
   $("#hub_container .dataTable").dataTable({dom: 'frit', paging: false, fixedHeader: {header: true}});
   $("#node_container .dataTable").dataTable({dom: 'rit', paging: false, fixedHeader: {header: true}});
   $("#node_filter").keyup(function(){ $("#node_container .dataTable").DataTable().search(this.value).draw(); });
  });

 

block content
 div#status_message
  p Last message: #{uplinkjson.last_msg}
 div#hub_container
  div.dataTable_wrapper
   table.dataTable.display
    thead
     tr
      th Hub ID
      th Status
      th Nodes Seen
      th Nodes Owned
    tbody
     - each hub, l in uplinkjson.hubs
      - var nodes= 0
      - var owned= 0
      - each item, i in uplinkjson.hubs[l].nodes
       - nodes++
       - if (item.owned)
        - owned++
      tr
       td #[a(href="##{uplinkjson.hubs[l].hub_id}") #{uplinkjson.hubs[l].hub_id}]
       td= uplinkjson.hubs[l].status
       td= nodes
       td= owned
 div#node_container
  p.right Node Search: #[input#node_filter]
  - each it, t in uplinkjson.hubs
   div.dataTable_wrapper
    a(name='#{uplinkjson.hubs[t].hub_id}')
    h2
     | Hub: #{(t+1)+"/"+uplinkjson.hubs.length} &emsp;
     | Hub ID: #{uplinkjson.hubs[t].hub_id} &emsp;
     | Hub Address: #[a(href= "http://["+"#{uplinkjson.hubs[t].hub_addr}"+"]"+"/client") #{uplinkjson.hubs[t].hub_addr}] &emsp;
     | Status: #{uplinkjson.hubs[t].status}
    table.dataTable.display.compact
     thead
      tr
       th ID
       th Distance
       th Last Seen
     tbody
      - each item, i in uplinkjson.hubs[t].nodes
       tr(class="#{item.owned ? 'owned' : '' }")
        td= item.id.toString(16)
        td= item.distance
        td= new Date(1000 * item.last_seen)
```